# TCP Hole Punching (bypassed listening socket)

Tags: python, sockets, tcp, udp, hole-punching

Its been a few days since I'm playing around Hole Punching in order to have some kind of reliable behaviour, but I'm now at a dead end.

**UDP Hole punching works great**: *simply first send a packet to the remote, and get the remote to send a packet the otherway as it will land through the source NAT. Its rather reliable from what I tried*.

But now comes TCP... I don't get it.

Right now, I can establish a connection through NATs but **only with connecting sockets**:

```
A.connect(B) -> Crash agains't B's NAT, but open a hole in A's NAT.
B.connect(A) -> Get in A's NAT hole, reach A's connecting socket.
```

But now, the two sockets that sended the SYN packets for connection are connected.

You would think that I would have done it, got a connection through 2 NATs, hooray.

But the problem is that this is not a normal behaviour, and given to this paper: http://www.brynosaurus.com/pub/net/p2pnat/, I should be able to have a listening socket in parallel to the connecting socket.

So I did bind a listening socket, which would accept inbound connections.

But inbound connections **are always caught by the connecting socket and not the by the listening one...**

e.g:

```py
#!/usr/bin/env python3
from socket import *
from threading import Thread
Socket = socket

# The used endpoints:
LOCAL = '0.0.0.0', 7000
REMOTE = 'remote', 7000

# Create the listening socket, bind it and make it listen:
Listening = Socket(AF_INET, SOCK_STREAM)
Listening.setsockopt(SOL_SOCKET, SO_REUSEADDR, 1)
Listening.bind(LOCAL)
Listening.listen(5)

# Just start in another thread some kind of debug:
# Print the addr of any connecting client:
def handle():
    while not Listening._closed:
        client, addr = Listening.accept()
        print('ACCEPTED', addr)
Thread(target=handle).start()

# Now creating the connecting socket:
Connecting = Socket(AF_INET, SOCK_STREAM)
Connecting.setsockopt(SOL_SOCKET, SO_REUSEADDR, 1)
Connecting.bind(LOCAL)

# Now we can attempt a connection:
try:
    Connecting.connect(REMOTE)
    print('CONNECTED', Connecting.getpeername())
except Exception as e:
    print('TRIED', type(e), e)
```

Now with this script, just agree on a port with a friend or whatever, and execute it on one end's, the `Connecting.connect(...)` should run for a bit (waiting for timeout, because SYN packet crashed into the distant NAT, but fortunately opened a hole in his own NAT), meanwhile execute the script on the other end, now the `Connecting.connect(...)` will return because it will have connected.

The weirdest part being: The `Listening` socket **was never triggerred**.

Why ? How to get the listening socket to catch inbound connections over the connecting socket ?

Note: Closing the connecting socket does send something on the network which immediately close the hole, at least it does on my network.

2nd-Note: I'm on windows.

**Edit**: The main problem is that in any circumstance, this script outputs `CONNECTED [...]` rather than `CLIENT [...]`, which given some lecture should not happen.

Comment: Have you tried to get packet capture on listening side? Do you see SYN requests from remote side there?

Comment: Yes, as I said, both sockets on each sides (remote/local) do establish a connection, but not on the `Listening` socket...

Answer (score 2, accepted):

So, after more tests and readings, here's what I came to:

In fact, it is possible to bind a listen socket and a socket making outbound connections on the same address (ip, port).

But the behaviour of the sockets heavily depends on the system / TCP stack implementation, as mentionned in http://www.brynosaurus.com/pub/net/p2pnat/ at *§4.3*:

> What the client applications observe to happen with their sockets during TCP hole punching depends on the timing and the TCP implementations involved. Suppose that **A**'s first outbound SYN packet to **B**'s public endpoint is dropped by NAT **B**, but **B**'s first subsequent SYN packet to **A**'s public endpoint gets through to **A** before **A**'s TCP retransmits its SYN. Depending on the operating system involved, one of two things may happen:
>
> - **A**'s TCP implementation notices that the session endpoints for the incoming SYN match those of an outbound session **A** was attempting to initiate. **A**'s TCP stack therefore associates this new session with the socket that the local application on **A** was using to connect() to **B**'s public endpoint. The application's asynchronous connect() call succeeds, and nothing happens with the application's listen socket.
>     Since the received SYN packet did not include an ACK for **A**'s previous outbound SYN, **A**'s TCP replies to **B**'s public endpoint with a SYN-ACK packet, the SYN part being merely a replay of **A**'s original outbound SYN, using the same sequence number. Once **B**'s TCP receives **A**'s SYN-ACK, it responds with its own ACK for **A**'s SYN, and the TCP session enters the connected state on both ends.
> - Alternatively, **A**'s TCP implementation might instead notice that **A** has an active listen socket on that port waiting for incoming connection attempts. Since **B**'s SYN looks like an incoming connection attempt, **A**'s TCP creates a new stream socket with which to associate the new TCP session, and hands this new socket to the application via the application's next accept() call on its listen socket. **A**'s TCP then responds to **B** with a SYN-ACK as above, and TCP connection setup proceeds as usual for client/server-style connections.
>     Since **A**'s prior outbound connect() attempt to **B** used a combination of source and destination endpoints that is now in use by another socket, namely the one just returned to the application via accept(), **A**'s asynchronous connect() attempt must fail at some point, typically with an “address in use” error. The application nevertheless has the working peer-to-peer stream socket it needs to communicate with **B**, so it ignores this failure.
>
> The first behavior above appears to be usual for BSD-based operating systems, whereas the second behavior appears more common under Linux and Windows.

So I'm actually in the first case. On my Windows 10.

This implies that in order to make a reliable method for TCP Hole Punching, I need to bind a listening socket at the same time as a connecting socket, but I later need to detect which one triggered (listening or connecting) and pass it down the flow of the application.

Comment: The only thing bothering me being that I only saw one of the two behaviour, but I guess I'll keep this paragraph as granted and will act accordingly.

Comment: Do you have code example ? how did you resolve this ?

Comment: @Amar You can inspire yourself from the code I wrote in the original question. My issue was about the behavior I observed, which seems to be normal according to http://www.brynosaurus.com/pub/net/p2pnat/. So depending on your platform different behaviors can happen. It's then up to your application to detect which behavior was triggered. I do not have any more code to share.

Answer (score 1):

**Why listen socket is not triggered**

I think the answer is somewhere here. TCP connection is defined by tuple of four elements:

- Local address
- Local port
- Remote address
- Remote port

When you establish TCP connection you create binding from this tuple to the connecting socket on local host.

When SYN is sent via NAT it creates binding:
 - Local address/port -> Public address/port

When remote side sends its SYN to the Public address/port this addresses are translated to Local address/port and delivered to local machine. On this machine this connection is not distinguishable from initial connection  and successfully established (with SYN/ACK).

This means that no INITIAL SYN is received on local side.

**How to get the listening socket to catch inbound connections over the connecting socket?**

It is impossible with source NAT. To accept new connection behind NAT you need destination NAT that maps some public IP/Port to you private IP/port

Comment: Thank you again for your answers, its really enjoyable not being alone on this problem :)

Now, if I get you right, your saying that I can't accept connections because my NAT has not any redirection ?
Because its the thing I am trying to get around with Hole Punching.

Now, based on this, then I could run the script given as example with `REMOTE = 'localhost', 7000` and it should work the way intended ?
No more NAT, packets are sent locally.

Well, it is actually doing the same thing: The connecting socket catches the connection, the listening socket does not.

Comment: (btw it does not matter which socket I bind first, the connecting socket always has priority over the listening/accepting one, sigh)

Comment: (maybe I did not fully understand you tho)

Comment: You can't accept client because NAT maps exactly one connection And there are two cases: 1) you send packet that matches that connection and this packet is accepted within connection 2) you send packet that mismatch  connection or its state (sequence number space etc) and you will get RST.

Comment: Also I think if you could to open new session from outside then it would be big security hole in the NAT.

Comment: I get your point. But then if I try it with my remote being  `localhost`, my listening socket should be able to accept a connection, rather than my connecting socket establishing a connection to another connection (`A.connect(B) <==CONN==> B.connect(A)`) ? But from what I did even on localhost the listening socket isn't catching the connection.

Comment: Because the same connection identification reason. When you establish second connection you send SYN to the existing (connecting) connection and operation system doesn't consider it as new connection. If you remove Connecting.bind(LOCAL) on second client you will get new connection.

Comment: Yes, but if I was to unbind the `Connecting` socket, I would lost my garentee on the address, as I need to know exactly on which endpoint to send packets from/to. Anyway I think I figured out the problem, which seems to be implementation depend. See my answer below, feel free to comment if I missed something :)